# How to use the next_rails gem for dual booting on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, next-rails

I am using the `next_rails` gem for dual booting and am ready to test on heroku, which I normally do by `git push staging master`. How do I test the next rails version on heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dual-Boot**

I'm assuming you already dual-booted the Rails application, so you just need to deploy your main branch, and changing the BUNDLE_GEMFILE value will change between the current and next Rails version.

if you haven't dual-booted your app follow this article https://www.fastruby.io/blog/upgrade-rails/dual-boot/dual-boot-with-rails-6-0-beta.html

**Compatible Buildpack**

Now as for being able to run the next rails version on Heroku, you should use this forked buildpack https://github.com/fastruby/heroku-buildpack-multiple-gemfiles, the official Heroku build seems unprepared to do that.

Here is this article for more info https://www.fastruby.io/blog/how-to-run-multiple-versions-of-rails-on-heroku.html

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should be able to set the `BUNDLE_GEMFILE` Heroku environment variable to `Gemfile.next, and then just push it to staging` e.g.

```
heroku config:set  BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile.next -r staging

git push staging master
```

Unfortunately there appears to be an [issue](https://github.com/fastruby/next_rails/issues/71#issuecomment-1253028223) with the Heroku ruby buildpack. My work around is as follows

a) use the next_rails gem as documented for development server and development tests

b) Once ready for testing deployment, create a new branch, with the only change is for the Gemfile to go from:

```
...
if next?
  gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.3.1'
  gem "sprockets-rails"
else
  gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.6.1'
end
```

to:

```
...
 gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.3.1'
```

And deploy that branch to staging. This branch only needs to be merged with master when you want to test out staging.

If the issue is resolved, I will update this answer.